# Screen touch simulation on Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, touch

I'd like to create a simple application for Android that would automate some processes that happen in different applications that I don't have under my control at all. Is there any way to get pixel color and simulate screen touch while my application runs in background?

Let's say I want to wait for a certain pixel to turn red (`#FF0000`), can I use `GetPixel(x,y)` to get the color and then simulate a screen touch event such as a swipe across the screen?

I tried to Google this but I've got nothing useful at all and now I'm quite desperate about this.

Comment: Could you please give some more background to your use case? Maybe there is a roundabout way of doing this.

Comment: Giving touch permissions input is not within standard Android permissions. I know an app called Tasker is able to do this but only if you're phone is rooted.

Comment: @Sipty Let's say (for example) that this application is supposed to sit silently in background (with user's knowledge and permission, it's not any kind of malware, really) and when notification appears, this application with slide down, open notifications screen and tap the latest notification. But the point is to make it looks just like a human did that. (I repeat, it's not any kind of malicious software and it's only for my use and not supposed to be ever distributed to anyone else)

Comment: @AlexCrist I'm aware of this and it's for obvious reasons, but in this case I'm talking about application used only by myself so it doesn't have to meet the Play Store security requirements. If you can think of any solution, even if it applies only to rooted devices, please let me know.

Comment: @user3043260 Unfortunately, I'm not sure how you might program that. Though if you haven't used Tasker before, maybe give it a look over. It could have the functionality you're looking for :-)

Comment: @AlexCrist I took a look at the official Tasker guide which explains how the applications works and shows some possible reasons to use it. But my problem is unfortunately far more complex than what Tasker is capable of from what I've seen. Anyways, thanks for your help and thanks for correcting the grammar in my question.

Answer (score 1):

I had to search a bit for this. I was also looking for this solution.

**NO ROOTING REQUIRED FOR THIS:**
If you want to repeat a sequence of steps like fill a form, repeat game steps because redoing is boring, You can try : **[FREP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.x0.strai.frep&hl=en)** Android App from Play Store(Link).

If you want to add conditional scenarios like, when you play Clash of Clans with home Wifi, turn data automatically and disable wifi ( Because Airtel Wifi in India is unpredictable and can make you loose the clan war!!) use, **[Macro Droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid&hl=en)** from Play Store.

You can try these as well:
**[Mahiro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.prohiro.macro&hl=en)**
Many apps are available based on **[Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en)** like, **[Auto Input](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autoinput&hl=en)**. You can maybe code/write macro to make personal solution with this Tasker App.

Comment: The point was to make the whole thing myself by programming it. Using 3rd party tools seems like a terrible practice whenever there's a suitable substitution. There's also an app called Automate for conditional control of the OS, but I wanted to make a pixel-bot on Android, which seems to be impossible and none of these apps are a sufficient substitution.